# CSS hover property not working while having canvas animated background

Tags: html, css, canvas

I have used the pre-written code from Codepen which uses Canvas and webGL for the animated background on my body but by using it now my hover property is not working, also the sizing of my background is different which goes below the view height and also extends a bit horizontally in the screen too.

How can I fix that, below is my code.

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <nav class="navbar">
      <ul class="menu">
        <li>
          <a href="">Home</a>
          <a href="">About Us</a>
          <a href="">Events</a>
          <a href="">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="main_section">
      <!-- GRADIENT  -->
      <canvas id="gradient-canvas"></canvas>
      <img src="./Assets/final_logo (2).png" alt="Logo" />
    </div>

    <script src="gradient.js"></script>
  </body>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  /* font-family: var(--body-font); */
  color: var(--text-dark);
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* padding: 0 0 0 0; */
  background-color: var(--white);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

/* NAVBAR */

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: var(--spacing-md);
  background-color: var(--white);
}
.menu {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1000px;
}
.menu li {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
}
.menu a {
  color: var(--logo-colour);
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.menu a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* GRADIENT */

.main_section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.main_section img {
  position: absolute;
}

#gradient-canvas {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  --gradient-color-1: #fefdfc;
  --gradient-color-2: #d9c5b6;
  --gradient-color-3: #b99b7d;
  --gradient-color-4: #856351;
}
```

I tried changing the display properties but then the whole thing got messed up and for the sizing I am not able to understand why it actually occurs.

Comment: You don’t seem to have included the bit which  does things with the canvas so there is no way we can help debug the code. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I'm guessing in the original the canvas was probably also absolutely positioned, and either moved below the content using `z-index`, or had `pointer-events: none` applied to it, to let mouse pointer events pass through. All things we could easily verify, if you included a _link_ to what you are actually talking about, instead of just saying "from Codepen."

Answer (score 0):

Add vendor prefixes for width and height properties for better cross-browser consistency:

```css
#gradient-canvas {
  width: -webkit-fill-available;
  width: -moz-available;
  width: fill-available;
  height: -webkit-fill-available;
  height: -moz-available;
  height: fill-available;
}
```